# HTML button, returning javascript as undefined.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope, undefined

I have been trying to execute the following in to a project I am working on.

To put it simply, when I click a button I want to be able to add a list item to the  that is directly above it. java script I have defined is below:

```js
function CritHandoff(IDNumber, Description, Status) {
    this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
    this.Description = Description;
    this.Status = Status;
}

function AddCritHandoff() {    
    var result = '';
    var Temp = new CritHandoff("ID123456", "This is a description", "Active");
    result += $('#CritHandoff').html("<li>"+Temp.IDNumber+"</li>");
    return result;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <h1 class="Crit" style="color:red">Critical Handoff:</h1>

    <ul id="CritHandoff">
        
    </ul>
    <button type="button" onclick="AddCritHandoff()">Test</button>
```

when I Attempt to execute after the page has loaded, and click the button, the debugger kicks in and says that AddCritHandOff() is undefined. However, if I change the code as such

```js
$(function AddCritHandoff() {    
    var result = '';
    var Temp = new CritHandoff("ID123456", "This is a description", "Active");
    result += $('#CritHandoff').html("<li>"+Temp.IDNumber+"</li>");
    return result;
});
```

The result will be that it executes on pageload with out issue.

My question is:

Is this just an issue of Scope? Although it mentions as the object is undefined, it seems to me that it was defined, just not at the time I click the button.

How else can I go about this?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Can you give us more of your code? Where are you defining AddCritHandoff? What would cause it to be defined "after" you click the button?

Comment: In you example js code is not inside script tag. Which means that if you take you code and put into page it won't be treated as js. Can you show as how you include this code into page? Is it in separate file? If so - where is the link? Or it is inlined in tag script? If so - can we see your head/body/scrtip tags?

Comment: Move it to  seperate JS file and add $(function() {---}); around both functions. It's not loading the AddCritHandoff function because it cannot recognize $('#CritHandoff') due to the fact jQuery isn't "ready".

Comment: You are concatenating a String with jQuery. How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched .**html** to .**append** and it works. - hope this helps

```js
function CritHandoff(IDNumber, Description, Status) {
  this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
  this.Description = Description;
  this.Status = Status;
}

function AddCritHandoff() {
  var result = '';
  var Temp = new CritHandoff("ID123456", "This is a description", "Active");
  result += $('#CritHandoff').append("<li>" + Temp.IDNumber + "</li>");
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="Crit" style="color:red">Critical Handoff:</h1>

<ul id="CritHandoff">

</ul>
<button type="button" onclick="AddCritHandoff()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating a String with a jQuery Object. I would do this instead:

```
$(function(){
function CritHandoff(ID, description, status){
  this.ID = ID;
  this.description = description;
  this.status = status;
}
function addCritHandoff() {
  var crit = new CritHandoff("ID123456", "This is a description", "Active"), res = crit.ID;
  $('#CritHandoff').html('<li>'+res+'</li>');
  return res;
}
// I would have this as external JavaScript and run the onclick here as well after giving your button an id or something
});
```

I made some changes, for conventional reasons.